# Yield Return All Remaining Items

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have an IEnumerable list of items from which I yield items. Within the IEnumerable, I am parsing strings which I split with a regex (splits the string by spaces). The string is split into what I refer to as 'sections'. After getting the 5th and 6th sections, I need to get all sections after that, how can I do that without specifying the explicitly? Here is what I have so far:

```
            yield return new Item
            {
                Product = sections[5],
                Price = sections[6],
               // Medadata = sections[?],  ////This part is comprised of many sections
            };
```

Comment: Can you confirm what data type is your `Metadata` property? e.g. `string`, `string[]`, something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Skip`:

```
Medadata = sections.Skip(7).ToArray()
```

It skips the number of items in the parameter and will continue reading from there on, yielding the 'remaining' items.

If you want to put all the remaining items in a single string, you can join them (I used a space as separator as example):

```
Medadata = string.Join(" ", sections.Skip(7))
```

Comment: Seems like a reasonable assumption, however it would be nice for the OP to confirm data types to validate this answer. For example, OP may be trying to convert it back to a space separated string...

Comment: @Patrick Hofman Well, getting this: cannot implicitly convert type string[] to string. This is the regex used for the split: Regex(@"[\s]+|[\t]");

Comment: Sounds like `Metadata` is of type `string`, so make it `string[]` or look at `string.Join` to concatenate the remaining items in `parts[]`.